# wordpress jquery is not responding as dependency

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have converted a html ecommerce template into woocommerce. but it is not working properly.the nivo slider and some other product is not working. maybe they are not finding wordpress jquery. although I enqueue custom jquery and other js file. here are the nivo slider js code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideshow').nivoSlider();
}
```

);

its dependencies is jquery 1.7.1

Comment: Wordpress usually already comes with jQuery, just without the `$` namespace. Replace that with `jQuery` and it should work.

Comment: Start by looking in browser console for errors. The error thrown is most likely very easily searched on web to get an idea what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if there's an issue with jQuery like `$ is not defined` then you need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Your new code will be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#slideshow').nivoSlider();
}
```

Now, if you need a jQuery version other than the one WP uses. You can deregister and enqueue your specific jQuery again. Add this to your `functions.php` file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'URL_OF_YOUR_NEW_JQUERY_FILE', array(), NULL, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
});
```

Comment: Dear bro junaid many many thanks to you. it's really working.

Comment: If this answer helped you, be sure to mark it the right answer so others may find it useful.